# Texture Look messy

Tags: texturing, uv

Apparently my Texture look a bit weird where some of the faces have diffrent output than the other one here's an example

[image]

as you can see that on the right its correct but on the left it was like only straight line. its not only happening on that part, other faces also has the same issues like that. can anyone tell what is the main problem Thank you.

UV Texture that i use :

[image]

UV map :

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell, how does your UVs look like?

Comment: there, i upload the photo of the texture

Comment: could you please pack the texture and share your file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18mUs-YEemSiiXs4Q-vKEGuEnygihw8-5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry I can only see a flat plane and a sphere, you must have made a mistake

Comment: Please share the object that is badly textured

Comment: hi, i send the file to your gmail already your gmail  clement.perrotte@gmail.com is that right ?

Comment: you can just reply it back to my Email that way it much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see if you select a face with the stretched texture, its UV is just a collapsed face:

[image]

So you need to unwrap this face again, or select all and choose the *Cube Projection* unwrap mode, which works fine with this kind of rectangular object.